# May sequential continuity of a map on compact sets fail to admit extrema?

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topological space. Is there an example of a *sequentially* upper-semicontinuous function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that does not admit a maximum point in $X$?

My very rough guess is that we cannot apply the usual Extreme-Value theorem here due to the lack of topological upper semicontinuity of the function $f$, since $f$ is only *sequentially* upper semi-continuous.

To be able to build such a function, I was thinking about a map that approaches its supremum at a point in $X$ that is a point in the closure but not in the sequential closure, in a way that this particular point is "not achievable by means of sequences". My intuition is that this may create troubles here. (but this is just an intuition).

Quick recall:
*A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called sequentially upper semicontinuous if
$ f(x) \ge \limsup _{k \rightarrow \infty} f\left(x_{k}\right) $ for any sequence $\left\{x_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subseteq X$ converging to $x \in X$.*

Comment: That's indeed possible. There are compact spaces that don't have any convergent sequences except the eventually constant ones, so on such a space, any function is sequentially continuous.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Could you please give a reference for such spaces?

Comment: I think an example can be $\beta \mathbb{N}$, the Stone-Čech compactification of the natural numbers. Then the only sequences that converge in $\beta \mathbb{N}$ are those which are eventually constant. And $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is a compact space that is not sequentially compact. I have the following as a reference: R. Engelking, General Topology, revised edition (Heldermann Verlag, 1989). Is there a wide study of these spaces?

Comment: @SonGohan : Thank you. I will check this out.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: I think $\beta\mathbb N$ works, but what I know for sure is that the spectrum of (the $C^*$-algebra) $L^{\infty}(0,1)$ (the complex homomorphisms with the weak $*$ topology) has this property. See for example Ch. 9 of my functional analysis notes here: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/ln.html

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Thank you. I will check this out.

Comment: $\beta\mathbb N$ and the spectrum of $L_\infty$ are examples of extremally disconnected compact spaces (a.k.a. Stonean spaces); in such spaces the only convergent sequences are the eventually constant ones. If $C(K)$ is order complete, then $K$ is extremally disconnected and vice versa.

Comment: I think that the maximum is attained if $X$ is *sequentially* compact.

Comment: @SonGohan: Yes, that'll work, or you could just map a countable set of points to $\mathbb Q\cap (0,1)$ and map the remaining points to $1/2$, say (this is of course very similar to what you suggested).